# Haskell - Pig Latin Translator

Tags: beginner, haskell, pig-latin

What improvements can I make to the following Pig Latin translator? So far, I've been wondering about the `FlexibleInstances` declaration, but I can't think of how to remove it (since it's required for `PigLatin String` in `instance`s, which is required for me to use `" "` in the `Monoid` instance; I need the extra type argument for `Functor`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Monad(when)
import Data.Char (toLower, toUpper)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

data PigLatin a = PigLatin a

instance Monoid (PigLatin String) where
  mempty = PigLatin ""
  mappend (PigLatin a) (PigLatin b) = PigLatin $ a ++ " " ++ b

instance Functor PigLatin where
  fmap f (PigLatin x) = PigLatin $ f x

instance Show (PigLatin String) where
  show (PigLatin s) = s

data English a = English a
  deriving (Eq)

safeTail :: [a] -> [a]
safeTail (_:xs) = xs
safeTail [] = []

quitCommand :: English String
quitCommand = English "\\q"

wordToPig :: English String -> PigLatin String
wordToPig (English word@(x:_)) = PigLatin $ if isVowel x
                                              then word ++ "yay"
                                              else rearrangedWord ++ "ay"
    where rearrangedWord = drop (length initialConsonants) word ++ initialConsonants
          initialConsonants = takeWhile isConsonant word
          isConsonant = not . isVowel
wordToPig (English "") = PigLatin ""

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel letter = letter `elem` ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

englishWords :: English String -> [English String]
englishWords (English input) = map English $ words input

sentenceToPig :: English String -> PigLatin String
sentenceToPig = fmap (capitalize . safeTail . map toLower) . foldl mappend mempty . map wordToPig . englishWords

capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize (x:xs) = toUpper x : map toLower xs
capitalize [] = ""

prompt :: String -> IO (English String)
prompt promptInput = do
  putStr promptInput
  hFlush stdout
  input <- getLine
  return $ English input

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- prompt "> "
    when (input /= quitCommand) $ do
      print $ sentenceToPig input
      main
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/126993/9357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let it derive the  Functor declaration:

```
data PigLatin a = PigLatin a deriving Functor
```

`foldl mappend mempty` <- You want `fold`.

`break` implements some of your stuff already.

I wouldn't introduce the types `PigLatin a` and `English a` in the first place. They just introduce wrapping without extra type-level structural info.

```
import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Char (toLower, toUpper)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import Control.Cateogry ((>>>)) -- flip (.)

--This turns empty words to yay, but words doesnt send empty words, right?
wordToPig :: String -> String
wordToPig = break (`elem` "aeiou") >>> \(initialConsonants, rest) ->
  rest ++ initialConsonants ++ if null initialConsonants then "yay" else "ay"

-- Your pig latin rules drop the first character of each sentence at the end?
sentenceToPig :: String -> String
sentenceToPig = capitalize . drop 1 . unwords . map wordToPig . words

capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize (x:xs) = toUpper x : map toLower xs
capitalize [] = ""

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr "> "
  hFlush stdout
  input <- getLine
  when (input /= "\\q") $ do
    print $ sentenceToPig input
    main
```

Comment: Thanks! `fold`, however, seems to have different semantics; also, the `newtype`s are required.

Comment: It shouldn't matter for `foldl mappend mempty`, which is associative by Monoid law. That your task assignment requires the `newtype`s doesn't change that they should not be there; just remember not to use them in this situation if you ever want to write code to actually use.