# Haskell Pig Latin Translator - v2

Tags: beginner, haskell, pig-latin

Thanks to Gurkenglas for the help with the previous iteration: [Haskell - Pig Latin Translator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126187/haskell-pig-latin-translator)!

Given the constraint that the `newtypes` are required, what improvements could be made to the following Pig Latin translator?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Char (toLower, toUpper)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

newtype PigLatin = PigLatin String

instance Show PigLatin where
  show :: PigLatin -> String
  show (PigLatin x) = x

instance Monoid PigLatin where
  mempty :: PigLatin
  mempty = PigLatin ""

  mappend :: PigLatin -> PigLatin -> PigLatin
  mappend (PigLatin a) (PigLatin b) = PigLatin $ a ++ " " ++ b

plMap :: (String -> String) -> PigLatin -> PigLatin
plMap f (PigLatin x) = PigLatin $ f x

newtype English = English String
  deriving (Eq)

safeTail :: [a] -> [a]
safeTail (_:xs) = xs
safeTail [] = []

quitCommand :: English
quitCommand = English "\\q"

wordToPig :: English -> PigLatin
wordToPig (English word@(x:_)) = PigLatin $ if isVowel x
                                              then word ++ "yay"
                                              else rearrangedWord ++ "ay"
    where rearrangedWord = drop (length initialConsonants) word ++ initialConsonants
          initialConsonants = takeWhile isConsonant word
          isConsonant = not . isVowel
wordToPig (English "") = PigLatin ""

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel letter = letter `elem` ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

englishWords :: English -> [English]
englishWords (English input) = map English $ words input

sentenceToPig :: English -> PigLatin
sentenceToPig = plMap (capitalize . safeTail) . foldl mappend mempty . map wordToPig . englishWords

capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize (x:xs) = toUpper x : map toLower xs
capitalize [] = ""

putStrNow :: String -> IO ()
putStrNow message = do
  putStr message
  hFlush stdout

prompt :: String -> IO English
prompt promptInput = do
  putStrNow promptInput
  input <- getLine
  return $ English input

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- prompt "> "
    when (input /= quitCommand) $ do
      print $ sentenceToPig input
      main
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem 1: Monoid

One subtle problem here:

```
instance Monoid PigLatin where
  mempty :: PigLatin
  mempty = PigLatin ""

  mappend :: PigLatin -> PigLatin -> PigLatin
  mappend (PigLatin a) (PigLatin b) = PigLatin $ a ++ " " ++ b
```

While it may not seem it, this is in fact an invalid `Monoid` instance. When we write `Monoid` instances we want certain laws to hold true so we can reason about them more easily. One such law: `mappend mempty x = x = mappend x mempty`. We want `mempty` to act as an "identity element" (like adding zero to or multiplying one by an integer). The extra space character makes this impossible. If the `Monoid` instance had been lawful, we could have replaced `foldl mappend mempty` with `mconcat`.

So the first thing I would do is to excise this `Monoid` instance and instead use `unwords`, as we'll detail below. This approach has the advantage of letting us delete `safeTail`.

### Problem 2: Slicing and dicing newtypes

The other thing we want to tackle is the problem of lifting `String` operations into our newtypes. We really want to lift `unwords :: [String] -> String` to `unwords :: [PigLatin] -> [PigLatin]`; that would obviate the need for the fold and the `Monoid` instance altogether. We also want to lift `String -> String` to `PigLatin -> PigLatin`, as evidenced by our `plMap` function. There's a similar problem with `englishWords`: we have a function `String -> [String]` but we want `English -> [English]` Haskell programmers are extraordinarily lazy and so we ask ourselves, *how can we do this in the least amount of code possible?*.

A common trick is to add a type variable:

```
newtype PigLatin a = PigLatin a
  deriving (Functor)

newtype English a = English a
  deriving (Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

This lets us derive instances for `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable`. It even admits an `Applicative` instance:

```
instance Applicative PigLatin where
  pure =
    PigLatin
  (<*>) (PigLatin a2b) (PigLatin a) =
    PigLatin (a2b a)
```

But *why*? Let's break down these typeclasses one by one.

#### Functor

One of our best friends. With `Functor`, `plMap = fmap`. The compiler automatically knows how to lift functions of type `String -> String` to `PigLatin String -> PigLatin String`. Not having to write any code is the best code there is. In fact, the compiler can even lift any type `a -> a` to `PigLatin a -> PigLatin a` even if in the end we only want to deal with `PigLatin String` values.

#### Foldable and Traversable

Having these two instances around permits the almight `traverse`. This humbly named function does something very very useful as it has type `(a -> [b]) -> English a -> [English b]`, which is *exactly* what we need to lift `words` up through our `English` newtype. When we choose to equip `English` with a `Foldable` and a `Traversable` instance we are granted the keys to this wonderful kingdom. The end result is this function

```
englishWords :: English String -> [English String]
englishWords =
  traverse words
```

Which is hardly long enough to worth defining!

#### Applicative

I fibbed earlier as it turns out that `traverse` actually has type

```
(Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

This unwieldy amalgam of variables and arrows can be broken down thusly. You can choose any types `f, t` and as long as there's an `Applicative f` and a `Traversable t` instance the compiler will do what you please.

Up above we chose `f ~ []` (the list type) and `t ~ English`. What if instead we were to choose `f ~ PigLatin` and `t ~ []`? Well then we would have a very interesting function of type `(a -> PigLatin b) -> [a] -> PigLatin [b]`.

Notice that `wordToPig` has type `English String -> PigLatin String`, which means `traverse wordToPig` would have type `[English String] -> PigLatin [String]`, which is *exactly* what we want. Why?

```
sentenceToPig :: English String -> PigLatin String
sentenceToPig =
  fmap (capitalize . unwords) . traverse wordToPig . traverse words
```

Because that allows us to reach for our old friend `fmap`. `capitalize . unwords` takes `[String]` to `String`, which means when we lift it up with `fmap` we get a function `PigLatin [String] -> PigLatin String`. Exactly what we need.

#### Coercible, the hidden typeclass

One thing you may not be aware of is that GHC generates a `Coercible` instance for all newtypes. What this means is [a little too complicated to go into detail here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html), but the end result is that you can type `coerce (PigLatin "hello") :: String` and get back `"hello" :: String`. Both the `"hello" :: String` and the `PigLatin "hello" :: PigLatin String` have the same in-memory representation, as guaranteed by the `newtype` keyword, and thus this poses no problem for the runtime. I like to use it for short scripts and it's especially handing for printing out newtypes. I noticed you defined a `Show` instance, and I think that's OK too. But I thought I'd bring it up since it's often overlooked.

### Altogether now

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Coerce (coerce)
import Data.Char (toLower, toUpper)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

newtype PigLatin a = PigLatin a
  deriving (Functor)

newtype English a = English a
  deriving (Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Applicative PigLatin where
  pure = PigLatin
  (<*>) (PigLatin a2b) (PigLatin a) = PigLatin (a2b a)

quitCommand :: English String
quitCommand = English "\\q"

wordToPig :: English String -> PigLatin String
wordToPig (English word@(x:_)) =
  PigLatin $ if isVowel x
             then word ++ "yay"
             else rearrangedWord ++ "ay"
  where
    rearrangedWord =
      drop (length initialConsonants) word ++ initialConsonants
    initialConsonants =
      takeWhile isConsonant word
    isConsonant =
      not . isVowel
wordToPig (English "") =
  PigLatin ""

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel letter = letter `elem` "aeiou"

sentenceToPig :: English String -> PigLatin String
sentenceToPig =
  fmap (capitalize . unwords) . traverse wordToPig . traverse words

capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize (x:xs) = toUpper x : map toLower xs
capitalize [] = ""

putStrNow :: String -> IO ()
putStrNow message = do
  putStr message
  hFlush stdout

prompt :: String -> IO (English String)
prompt promptInput = do
  putStrNow promptInput
  input <- getLine
  return $ English input

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- prompt "> "
  when (input /= quitCommand) $ do
    putStrLn . coerce $ sentenceToPig input
    main
```

Comment: Thanks so much! My original approach was to add the type variable, but it would be non-sensical for `PigLatin` or `English` to have any type parameter but `String`, and I'd like to make illegal states unrepresentable (I love that phrase so much).